# How to use the mode master with the ath5k driver?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, access-point, wlan

In [this page](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/ath5k#features), they says that we can use the AP mode with the ath5k driver since linux 2.6.31

I am using Ubuntu Karmic with : linux 2.6.31-16-generic

I would like to share my eth0 WAN connection creating a wlan0 LAN.
Browsing on the Internet, I saw that we can use hostapd to do that.

The main problem is this command :

```
$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

How can I make my AP mode working with Karmic ?

Comment: I am having the same problem with my `MacBook Pro Santa Rose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HostAP is quite particular about the combination of cards and drivers that it can support. Have you tried it with the madwifi drivers instead?

Comment: Thanks after a little restart and thinking it works fine ;)

Comment: How should I install it ?